# Java script regex to accept multiple values including empty in Mountebank predicates

Tags: javascript, regex, mountebank

I was trying to accept multiple values including empty in Mountebank predicates.

As per below in the query parameter I want to accept both false and empty value.

Tried below and it doesn't accept neither `isValid=false` nor `isValid=`

```
"predicates":[
   {
      "matches":{
         "method":"GET",
         "path":"/accounts",
         "query":{
            "isValid":"/false|^null$/"
         }
      }
   }
],
"responses":[
   {
      "....."
   }
]
```

I tried below option as well as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18496746/2303693)

```
"isValid":"/false.^null$|^null$.false/"
```

Comment: `"matches": { "data": "^(first)?$" }`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, This worked, please add this as the answer with describing the syntax if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
"matches": {
    "data": "^(?:false)?$" 
}
```

Here,

- `^` - matches start of string
- `(?:false)?` - an optional (due to `?` at the end) [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions) that matches a char sequence `false` one or zero times
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: As per the question I believe it should be `false` NOT `first`. Further mine worked without `colon` and leading `?` i.e.   `^(false)?$`

Comment: @SMPH If it is JavaScript, you can rely on the non-capturing group, too. Capturing groups keep the captured value in the match object, which is a redundant overhead.